# Jump to editor shortcut in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I can use <kbd>F12</kbd> to jump **to project tree** (if it was the last tool that I used), but is there a shortcut for jumping **back to editor?**

Comment: If you're using ESC for something else (e.g. vim), upvoting this will help the situation: Upvoting this should help: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116865

Comment: Suggest you alt+1 for that, nearer from your fingers positions

Answer (score 587, accepted):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> usually brings the focus back to the editor.

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to bind additional key combinations to this action?

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan, I'm afraid, no.

Comment: This is broken in VIM-emulator mode (escape does mode switching instead), and there is no way to bind another keystroke to focusing the editor.

Comment: For reference I have reported this issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-591

Comment: Hi! That doesn't seem to work with terminal, sadly. Know of any workaround ?

Comment: Exactly what @Ven said.  Some tool windows only respond to Shift-Escape, which works but hides the tool window.

Comment: I previously requested that this be configurable: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116865

Comment: There are a few workarounds for terminal. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23860667/722929

Comment: Not always. When I select something  in tool window when I press esc it deselects it. Second Esc will go to editor but that's not convenient as it requires feedback - check if I'm in editor, if not press esc again. Also I would like to keep selection in tool window, not remove it

Comment: Esc, F4, Alt+Home, Crlt+Shift+A "Edit" does not work if you have some toolbars in windowed mode. Is there any other option?

Comment: @PavolLiška there is no other option, [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: Go to Settings | Tools | Terminal and disable "Override IDE shortcuts" option - it will help to navigate from Terminal to editor using `ESC`.

Answer (score 25):

With Alt + Home you can actually put focus on selecting the file and hit enter in order to go to the editor.

Esc is not always going to put the focus on editor.

For those on Mac (you don't have a Home key), use Command + E to open the recent files then hit enter.

Comment: I'll make useful extensive usage of this one here!! Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Pressing F4 (`Jump to Source` action) in a selected resource in the Project View opens the editor with focus.

Comment: This is really annoying that I had to add Enter key as a second shortcut (alongside with F4) to open and *focus* file from Project view

Comment: Best workaround for me because it doesn't hide any other window. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Another easy way to get from Terminal to Editor (on Mac) with two keys that are close together: Press `⌘1` to go to the project tool window, then hit `Esc`.

Comment: Or simply press `⌘1` twice; much easier :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ctrl + tab` Navigate between files opened in the editor, and tool windows.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a workaround, but, on mac os the following keystrokes work,

```
[ SHIFT + CMD + A ] > type "edit" > [ ENTER ]
```

So, I created a Service using Automator as follows,

- receives no input
- active for my IDE only ( phpstorm )
- runs an AppleScript ( see below )

Then I mapped the Service via "System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services" to

```
[ CTRL + OPTION + CMD + i ]
```

The Automator Service, contains the following AppleScript,

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"

        keystroke "A" using {shift down, command down}

        delay 0.2
        keystroke "edit"

        delay 0.2
        keystroke return

    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Comment: I didn't know this was possible, thanks for posting this answer!

Comment: great answer here - i'll use this as a template for other commands as well

Comment: Thank you.  Shift+Cmd+A followed by Esc also seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant way found in mac: `ctrl + tab + p`

`ctrl + tab`: open recent file, always last file opened
`ctrl + p`: last line in mac default keymap

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect solution, since <kbd>Escape</kbd> doesn't work if your other Tool Window is a Terminal, Windowed... as a result there is an open ticket on Jetbrains, bug tracking site see [this link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116865).

Also, if you have "Autoscroll to Source" disabled (default state in Intellij):

- <kbd>Escape</kbd> puts cursor in file currently visible in editor (As mentioned in the other Answers)
- <kbd>F4</kbd> puts cursor in file currently selected in the **Project** view.