# How to jump from Intellij terminal to editor with shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that you can jump from almost all windows in Intellij IDEA to the editor window with <kbd>Esc</kbd>. In Intellij's terminal window, this does not work. Does anyone know how to do this with a keyboard shortcut? This would be nice since I can jump from my editor to the terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> but I cannot do it the other way without using my mouse.

Comment: ctrl-tab gives you quick switch - from memory i believe `0` is editor, does that help?

Comment: @vikingsteve `0` is `Ant Build`

Comment: Thanks, right, it's just ctrl-tab. See Mark Vedders answer for details.

Comment: Upvoting this should help: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116865

Comment: For Terminal panel. Just use `Shift + Esc` from @Andrey mentioned below.

Comment: For those who WANT to stay in Terminal when Esc is hit (for example, if you're doing command-line editing with vi) but are getting burned by the new behaviour (2019.2 CE?) where it changes to the editor...there's a plug-in called "Switch Focus To Editor" that's responsible for this. Unassign the Esc key there, and you're back in business.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

***UPDATE - March 2016***

Since this question is getting some attention, I wanted to remind everyone that you can toggle between the editor and the terminal window easily enough with a built in action. By default it is mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>. To check other mappings, view it in the menu at *View > Tool Windows > Terminal*. Alternatively go to the [Working with Embedded Local Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html) web help page and change the Keymap option in the upper right corner and scroll to the very end (just above the "See also" section) where it says: "Toggle between the embedded local terminal and editor by pressing...". You can remap this action in *Settings > Keymap > Other > Terminal*

The main "issue" this question discusses is if there is a way to return from the terminal window to the editor without closing the terminal window.

[End March 2016 update]

===================================================

Some options I can think of at the moment.

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> a second time will take you back to the editor, but will hide the terminal window.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> will take you to the navigation bar, then hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> will take you to the editor. If you do this often enough, to eliminate the need for the double sequence you could record a Macro (*Edit > Macros*) with the sequence. Then map it to a shortcut (*Settings > [IDE Settings] > Keymap > Macros*). The nice thing about this option is that it will work from any tool window. So you can get use to it as a consistent "Return to the Editor" shortcut.
3. While there is no editor option in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher  that @vikingsteve mentions, you could do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Again, you could record that to a macro.

If I think of any other ideas, I'll add them.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari which solution worked for you? Which version/OS are you on?

Comment: @dev Macros + Assign a shortcut to macro.

Comment: opt-f12 did it for me in phpStorm on OSX. LIfesaver!

Answer (score 36):

Ubuntu:

```
alt + 2(twice) - jump from the terminal to the editor
alt + F12 - open the terminal
```

Mac:

```
cmd + 2(twice) - jump from the terminal to the editor
options + F12 (this shortcut toggles the terminal window on and off)
```

Comment: On my machine this just inputs the "TM" character twice .. `™™`

Comment: How do you configure IntelliJ to use this shortcut? I have the same result as hasen.

Comment: @Logan I did not configure. It just works on my machine (Ubuntu)

Comment: cmd + 2 twice on Mac

Comment: Alt+2 toggles the favorites as of the current (Merch 2021) EAP.

Comment: where is F12 in Mac ?

Comment: If it doesn't work on your Mac, try Opt+Fn+F12 (Volume Up media key).

Answer (score 25):

It might be an option to disable `Preferences > Tools > Terminal > Override IDE shortcuts`

<kbd>Esc</kbd> works after that

Comment: Great solution, once this option is unchecked it's possible to directly move to another window (for example "Version control") without having to go to the editor window first.

Comment: Do you know how I can use a similar solution for the debug (also named Run) window?

Answer (score 15):

**Running IDEA 13 on OSX**

Expanding on Mark Vedder's answer, here's my experience so far:

1. <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>(Alt+F12) (`Terminal`) will toggle the terminal tool window visibility, so it will take you back to the editor once hidden. Similar effect with <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⎋</kbd>(Shift+Esc)(`Hide Active Tool Window`), which will hide the active tool window, putting focus back on the editor.
   **No good if you want Terminal visible at all times**
2. While it's a great idea to record a macro that will take you back to the editor through scripted interaction, it fails to work in practice. For one thing, Terminal will intercept most key strokes, so you won't be able to trigger the macro. Even when you do manage to trigger the macro through its shortcut key from some other tool window (the Project tool window for example), it won't work (even though `Script execution finished` will display along the bottom of the IDEA window)
   **Doesn't work**
3. <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇥</kbd> won't work either as the Terminal window seems to intercept most key combinations. But even if it did work, it would switch the editor to the next file, so you'd still need to do a <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⇥</kbd> to return to the original one (as Mark pointed out).
   **Doesn't work but don't really mind as it spares another annoyance**
4. While Terminal has focus, it appears some `Tools` shortcuts are still accessible **as long as you haven't reassigned them** in `Preferences->Keymap` (very important you don't touch these - I tried unassigning and reassigning <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>(`Project`) and it would no longer trigger from within Terminal!). Invoking any of these shortcuts **twice** will toggle that Tool window, eventually taking you back to the editor. For example, I don't normally use the `Favorites Tool Window` (i.e. not normally visible), so whenever I need to break out of Terminal I simply type <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> **x 2**.
   **Maybe works for you?**
5. The <kbd>⎋</kbd> key, when used on any `Tool Window`, will shift focus back to the editor. So, similar to (4.), first do <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> or any other working shortcut to move focus out of Terminal to a more well-behaved `Tool Window`, then <kbd>⎋</kbd>.
   **Same as (4.)**

Comment: `alt+2` twice is the winner

Comment: I would disagree. `Alt + 2` inputs odd `2` symbol in the terminal each time you want to focus on editor (at least on windows) which is pretty annoying

Comment: Cmd+2 to get to favorites followed by ESC works for me!

Comment: `alt+2` did not work for me. it types an odd symbol(trademark symbol) in the terminal. The other shortcuts mentioned here also closes the terminal window (on/off) which is annoying.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility:

```
Shift + Esc
```

(This one will close terminal panel)

Answer (score 5):

On OSX PhpStorm 8, <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> twice works. <kbd>⌥</kbd> + numbers are not likely to be assigned as [default] shortcuts on OSX as they are special characters like ™ (<kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>).

For me, only <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd>, and <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> work with this idea, <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> being the least disruptive as @dev suggests.

There is an [open ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119666) about the Terminal focus issue that might be worth following to see if this behaviour improves in the future.

Comment: ⌘  2 twice, worked for me too! I'm running IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate on El Capitan.

Answer (score 3):

**As of 2020, you can use the same key (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) to toggle between the terminal and the previous window you were in.**

Answer (score 1):

I believe the better answer is

> Alt + Home

This is because most of the answers like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> are about closing the terminal and hoping the focus goes back to the editor, but with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> the focus goes to selecting the editor and sometimes the focus is on the file but it actually is not opened. This way you can open it too.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**

This solution assumes that you want to leave the terminal and version control tab (or any tab) always open and don't want to close any of them. And you want to jump from terminal to editor using keybaord shortcut.

**Solution**

1. Assign <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> (or any other shortcut) to jump to terminal
2. You have already <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> to jump to version control tab
3. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This will take you to editor and both the version control tab and terminal will remain open
4. When you want to goto terminal just press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>

**Webstorm screenshot**

You can see my webstorm, I alway open two tabs at bottom. And you can also see the settings of terminal in this screenshot which are used to open it in split mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Terminal Tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> while in terminal) and drag the tab header to the editor area, just making it a "normal" tab.

Then you can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> for switching between editor tab and terminal tab (when in override IDE hotkeys mode), or split vertically, assign "go to next splitter" shortcut and use it for switching.

Answer (score 0):

- This will active the editor again
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone,

Editor/Terminal:
For going to the terminal you can use- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
and going to editor simply- <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Editor/Run:
But I am new to IntelliJ. I mostly have to use this "run terminal" for that you can use- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>,
for switching to run and switching back to the editor.

Answer (score -1):

Injellij -> Preference -> Key Map -> search "terminal" -> .

find or change the shortcut there