# Toggle between embedded terminal and editor while keep the terminal open

Tags: intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2 on OSX.

I understand [⌥F12 allows us to toggle between embedded terminal and editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html), but in this way the terminal disappears when focus moves to editor. Sometimes I'd like to switch focus from and to terminal with shortcut keys and still have the terminal opened so that I can tail logs.

My current workaround is to use both Terminal.app and IntelliJ IDEA and switch over by ⌘+Tab, but to me it's handy if I can do both in IntelliJ IDEA. Probably the embedded terminal and its use cases are designed to suite lightweight task that requires minimal attention, though.

Comment: What mode is the terminal in? (Click the gear in the top right of the terminal window - what is checked?)

Comment: Pinned and Docked are both checked. I referred to the document, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/viewing-modes.html#docked, and tried checking/unchecking some checkbox to apply some different setting combinations, but none of them seem to work...

Comment: OK, with the docked + pinned mode, the terminal stay opened when I switch focus to editor: clicking on editor window. This is the expected behaviour as officially documented.
However, with ⌥F12 shortcut, it is still assigned to "toggle terminal" so the embedded terminal still closes when this shortcut is used to... "toggle."
Found http://stackoverflow.com/a/26953327/694061 as a workaround to "switch" instead of "toggle."

Answer (score -1):

Your problem here is that the <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut isn't toggle focus, but toggle *open*. So essentially you are just opening and closing it.

After opening the terminal you should use the same command you use to switch between tabs in the editor (I believe it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> on OSX).

Your window mode is correct though - docked mode keeps it attached to the side/bottom of the window, and pinned mode keeps it from collapsing when losing focus, so keep those set.