# Escape is a shortcut I do not want in pycharm, how to change?

Tags: python, pycharm

In pycharm escape switches me to the editor window, how to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently you cannot easily change the behavior - **`Escape` is, unfortunately, hardcoded for the "Jump to Editor" action**. There is an open discussion on the topic (since 2013):

- [Add the ability to bind "Jump to Editor" to a key other than escape](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116865)
- [Jump to editor shortcut in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825270/771848)

There are though some workarounds for some of the screens you are pushing `Escape` in - for instance - [`Terminal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23860667/771848).