# how to move cursor from project view to editor in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard, shortcut

I want to use only keyboard working with Intellij.

I can easyly open `Project view` with short cut:

> Alt + 1

***How to move again to editor and leave `Project view` open?***

Without using mouse, of course.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jump to editor shortcut in Intellij IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825270/jump-to-editor-shortcut-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Escape` always brings you back to the editor.

If your `Project view` is closed, you need to pin it. Click on the little gear wheel and make sure, `Pinned Mode` is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Escape brings input focus back to the Editor window.  And Escape Escape brings the focus back *and* closes the popped up tool window.