# Jump to editor shortcut in Intellij IDEA from Windowed Mode

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

As for [Jump to editor shortcut in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825270/jump-to-editor-shortcut-in-intellij-idea) question <kbd>Esc</kbd> only works if you have your "windows" inside IDEA.

But how can I navigate back to the code if I have my window in "Windowed mode"?

I found <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> as an option, but it is not always convenient to use it.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your scenario, can you please be more explicit? Nonetheless, what about `CTRL` + `TAB` to use the switcher, or if you're opening a tool window just press the same combination again. Eg, `ALT` +  `9` to open the VCS window, and again `ALT` + `9` to close it?

Comment: @Morfic, real world scenario: 1) Make "Project" to "Windowed mode" 2) Move it to another monitor 3) Open any class and locate it via `Alt+F1` in "Project" 4) Then you want to jump back to the code and don't close "Project" window. You can't do it with `Alt+1`,becuase it will close "Project" and can't do it with `CLRT`+`TAB`, because it will move you to previously edited file.

Comment: If you locate the class/file in the `Project` window, you can press `F4` (go to source), or `CTRL` + `TAB` to open the switcher. Any of those useful as workaround in your situation?

Comment: @Morfic, yes, but not exactly. Because I described only one case of many. For example, I also use "Run" window in "Windowed mode" and I can't press `F4` from there. Only `CTRL+TAB` will work somehow, but I will need to press `CTRL+TAB` and then `CTRL+SHIFT+TAB` to bring the pointer to the most recent file, which is not very convenient. Or `CTRL+TAB` twice =)

Comment: I see, then I'm afraid I have no direct solution because I'm (currently) not aware of any direct short-cut that switches back to the editor. The closest thing is, as you said, `CTRL+TAB` and then maybe `UP` is easier to press than `CTRL+SHIFT+TAB`. Good luck :-)