# Intellij Idea: what is shortcut for main window

Tags: intellij-idea

Imaging the situation when you writing some code and then you wish to continue your work in the terminal. `Alt + F12` and you are in the terminal. After 1 sec you wish to continue to work under your code. So you need some shortcut that allows you return back to the code window (I would like to avoid using the mouse). What should I press for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal [has an option to override IDE shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG52k.png) which is enabled by default, this is done so that you can use common shortcuts in the terminal applications.

If you disable this option, you can use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get the focus back to the editor, otherwise it will be intercepted and can be used in the apps running in the terminal tool window.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will hide the Terminal tool window and move the focus back to the editor no matter if the option mentioned above is enabled or not.

For all the other cases <kbd>Esc</kbd> will work fine as [mentioned in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8828957/104891).